# plt.plot issue in pandas with categorical index DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, categorical-data

I have a DataFrame with categorical index like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

accidents_by_day=pd.DataFrame({'num_accidents':[5659,5298,4917,4461,4181,4038,3985],
                           'weekday':[7,1,6,5,4,2,3]})

weekday_map={1:'Sunday',2:'Monday',3:'Tuesday',4:'Wednesday',5:'Thursday',6:'Friday',7:'Saturday'}
new_index=(pd.CategoricalIndex(accidents_by_day.weekday.map(weekday_map)).
       reorder_categories(new_categories=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday',
                                          'Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],
                          ordered=True))
accidents_by_day.set_index(new_index,drop=True,inplace=True)
accidents_by_day.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

While The following works fine:

```
accidents_by_day.num_accidents.plot(kind='bar')
```

The `plt.plot(accidents_by_day.num_accidents)` gives an error

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    390             func = self._makefill
    391 
--> 392         ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
    393         for j in xrange(max(ncx, ncy)):
    394             seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

and `plt.plot([accidents_by_day.num_accidents])` produces an empty figure.

Could anyone explain what is happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot` takes two arguments, `x` and `y`: `plt.plot(x,y)`. If you only specify a single argument, `plt.plot(y)`, it is assumed that you want to plot against the numbers `0, ..., len(y)-1`. So what is possible here, is to plot

```
plt.plot(accidents_by_day.num_accidents.values)
```

The produced plot might however not be the desired one, since the dataframe index is not taken into account.

So you may stick to the usual `plt.plot(x,y)` and supply the index,

```
plt.plot(accidents_by_day.index.categories, accidents_by_day.num_accidents.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand your point, but shouldn't `accidents_by_day.num_accidents.plot()` and `plt.plot(accidents_by_day.num_accidents)` produce the same results? so how come one works and the other raise an error?

Comment: The categorical index is not understood by matplotlib.