# Linestyle graph cannot see x axis labels

Tags: python, pandas

I am testing a very simple exercise just plot the code below:

```
t = pd.Series([1,2,5,1,8], index=['a', 's', 'l', 'f', 'd' ])
t.plot(linestyle = '-', color = 'b', sharex = True)
```

but I cannot see the letters `a`, `s`, `l`, `f`, and `d`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

t = pd.Series([1,2,5,1,8], index=['a', 's', 'l', 'f', 'd' ]) 
plt.plot(t.index, t.values,linestyle = '-', color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

Image is in [the following link](https://postimg.cc/Pprh80Vs)

[Adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836076/9960542)